# How do I work with the REPA ByteString representation?

Tags: haskell

I want to use REPA arrays built from `ByteString` types. I can create an array with the `fromByteString` function that has the type `Array B sh Word8`. However, there is no equivalent `computeS` function for the `B` type arrays.

The biggest issue is that I want a `ByteString` type at the end, but the function `toByteString` requires a `Array B sh Word8` type which I cannot create.

It feels like the bytestring module in REPA is not fully implemented. As a comparison, the vector module provides `computeVectorS`, the foreignPointer module provides `computeIntoS`. Is there a reason that bytestrings are missing an equivalent function?

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how to produce an `Array B` with repa either. It has none of the relevant instances for that. Would you like to [open an issue](https://github.com/haskell-repa/repa/issues)?

One obvious and mostly safe workaround is to extract a pair `(Int, Int -> Word8)` from the delayed representation and use `unfoldrN` (the most fitting function I could find from the public API of bytestring).

A `ByteString` is really a decorated `ForeignPtr`, so you can use the `F` representation (which has a `Target` instance), get a `ForeignPtr` out, and call [`Data.ByteString.Internal.fromForeignPtr`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.8.1/docs/src/Data-ByteString-Internal.html#fromForeignPtr).